# simple fading in/out with jquery, is it worth it?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have read all your responses and come to the conclusion that is a bad idea all together. Thank you very much, multiple pages is so much easier anyway.

I am building a website and I don't want the page to refresh. My idea was that I would have 3 different divs of the same size fade in and out depending the the nav link the user selected.

Example code: (#about is the nav div and #about_main is the main div, and so on)

```
$('#about a').click(function() {
    $('#portfolio_main, #contact_main').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#about_main').delay(405).fadeIn();
    });
});

//hide all divs that ren't on portfolio link
$('#portfolio a').click(function() {
    $('#about_main, #contact_main').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#portfolio_main').delay(405).fadeIn();
    });
});

$('#contact a').click(function() {
    $('#about_main, #portfolio_main').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $('#contact_main').delay(405).fadeIn();
    });

});
```

This proves to be a problem as you can click on the `$('#about a')` 100 times and it will fire 100x. Also, if I click on many `a tags` quickly, the divs get all messed up.

Example: [My Site](http://philipimperato.com)

How can I have it so that it fades in and out easily and nicely? Is there way to unbind the click when the user has already clicked it? Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: don't do this.  it's bad for seo.  it's bad for analytics.  it's bad for bookmarks.  it's bad for back buttons.  most importantly, it's bad for the apparent objective of this site to detail your professional web development expertise

Comment: Please don't do this. This isn't how the Internet is meant to work. Have three pages, and link to them. Fading might be nice from an eye-candy stand point, but any developer worth their salt will look at that site and *not* hire you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with Robert that you should not do this, however, if you are compelled to do so you can check out this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xWu3C/2/

I didn't bring your styles over or anything but the principle is is the same.

Comment: Dude, even though your code gives the same issues, I appreciate the effort, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the obvious question of the wisdom of arranging your site this way -- first, you might want to set a fixed height for your container, so you don't get that jumping effect between transitions.

As to the overlapping animations, you should take a look at [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue today as well.  I came to the conclusion that sometimes flashy effects, though appealing, are just not appropriate.  Especially for something as large as what you are applying the effects to.  I would just redirect to another page.

I am not sure what server-side language you are using but your page can easily be separated into sections so that you can re-use the header and footer, i.e.  Asp.net master pages.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this questions asks "is it worth it?" so I will address that rather than "how to" posed in the question body.  The answer is:  No, please don't break the internet.